# Do I need anything to download to work with html5 in my computer?

Tags: html

Do I need anything to download to work with html5 in my computer?Or I can write it in the notepad as the usual html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is just another (the fifth) revision of the "usual" HTML standard. It mainly describes several new features, but still consists of plain text files and does not require any special tools on your computer.

The interesting question is whether your browser supports the new features of HTML5 (or rather: the browser of the person viewing your site), where *usually* none of the modern browsers (for IE that's 10+) should have serious issues.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need anything to run HTML5, just a text editor and browser of your choice. And yes text editor could be Notepad++